# ¿Cómo detectar que un elemento pasó por encima del otro?

Tags: javascript

Me interesa saber cuando el `span` rojo pasó, o mejor dicho, 'tocó' al span negro, esto es un ejemplo breve de lo que quiero lograr ya que me interesa aplicar el código en una polilínea. Alguna solución sin *event.clientX / event.clientY* ya que por las curvas de la polilínea podría fallar la precisión.

```js
let counter = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  document.querySelector(".flotante").style.left = counter + "%";
  counter++;
}, 1000);
```

```css
.calle {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.calle > span {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
}

span.flotante {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="calle">
  <span class="flotante"></span>
  <span></span>
</div>

<br><br>

<span>Tocado: No</span>
```

Comment: puedes obtener las coordenadas o dimensiones de cada elemento con [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) y validar de que si la coordenada a la izquierda del elemento rojo es mayor que del elemento negro, muestras un span que dica que se tocó.

Comment: para polígonos una solución es recorrer los vértices ( de a pares ) y detectar cuando [dos líneas se cruzan](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersecci%C3%B3n_de_dos_rectas) para círculos y "cajas" las formulas son mas simples [hay ejemplos en mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection) la versión [optimizada para poligonos se denomina SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem#Use_in_collision_detection) pero tiene ciertas limitaciones ( poligonos no convexos )

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías hacer es acceder a las coordenadas que tienen tus dos círculos (rojo y negro) utilizando el método [**`getBoundingClientRect()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) y saber dónde se posicionan, veamos un ejemplo para que sepas cómo funciona:

```js
let counter = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  const spanRojo = document.querySelector('.spanRojo');

  spanRojo.style.left = counter + '%';
  counter++;

  const spanRojoRect = spanRojo.getBoundingClientRect(); // Tengo acceso a las coordenadas.

  console.log(`Cord izq => ${spanRojoRect.left}`) // Obtenemos la coordenada izquierda del circulo rojo.
  console.log(`Cord der => ${spanRojoRect.right}`) // Obtenemos la coordenada derecha del circulo rojo.

}, 1000);
```

```css
.calle {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.calle > span {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
}

span.spanRojo {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="calle">
  <span class="spanRojo"></span>
  <span class="spanNegro"></span>
</div>
```

Como verás, cuando inicializamos al elemento con **`getBoundingClientRect()`**, podemos tener acceso a sus coordenadas y ver en qué coordenada se posiciona dicho elemento, y como el elemento va a ir moviéndose cada segundo, las coordenadas van a ir cambiando.

---

Ahora que sabemos esto, podemos obtener las coordenadas del círculo rojo y círculo negro para validar de que si la coordenada de la izquierda del círculo rojo es mayor que la coordenada del círculo negro (o sea, que si el círculo rojo pasa al círculo negro), ocultamos y mostramos dicho texto:

```
if (spanRojoRect.right > spanNegroRect.left && spanRojoRect.left < spanNegroRect.right) {
  siTocado.style.display = 'block';
  noTocado.style.display = 'none';
} else {
  siTocado.style.display = 'none';
  noTocado.style.display = 'block';
}
```

En donde éstos textos que se ocultarán o mostrarán, serán éstos **`<span>`** que te muestro a continuación:

```
<div class="calle">
  <span class="spanRojo"></span>
  <span class="spanNegro"></span>
</div>

<br/><br/>

<span id="noTocado">Tocado: No</span>
<span id="siTocado">Tocado: Sí</span>
```

---

Tu código final vendría a ser el siguiente:

```js
let counter = 0;

const siTocado = document.getElementById('siTocado'); // Obtengo al span => <span id="siTocado">Tocado: Sí</span>.
const noTocado = document.getElementById('noTocado'); // Obtengo al span => <span id="noTocado">Tocado: No</span>.

siTocado.style.display = 'none'; // Inicializamos ocultando al elemento "siTocado" (el que dice "Tocado: Sí").
noTocado.style.display = 'block'; // Inicializamos mostrando al elemento "noTocado" (el que dice "Tocado: No").

// Luego, ingresamos al setInterval(() => {...}, 1000);
setInterval(() => {
  const spanRojo = document.querySelector('.spanRojo'); // Obtengo al círculo rojo.
  const spanNegro = document.querySelector('.spanNegro'); // Obtengo al círculo negro.

  spanRojo.style.left = counter + '%'; // Al círculo rojo, cada 1 segundo le asigno un porcentaje a la izquierda.
  counter++; // el contador incremente de 1 en 1.

  const spanRojoRect = spanRojo.getBoundingClientRect(); // Obtengo la coordenada del círculo rojo.
  const spanNegroRect = spanNegro.getBoundingClientRect(); // Obtengo la coordenada del círculo negro.

  // Valido de que si las coordenadas de la izquierda / derecha del círculo rojo superan al del círculo negro, entra al if
  if (spanRojoRect.right > spanNegroRect.left && spanRojoRect.left < spanNegroRect.right) {
    siTocado.style.display = 'block'; // y entonces muestro el "Tocado: Si."
    noTocado.style.display = 'none'; // y oculto el "Tocado: No."
  } else { // de lo contrario...
    siTocado.style.display = 'none'; // oculto el "Tocado: Si."
    noTocado.style.display = 'block'; // muestro el "Tocado: No."
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
.calle {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.calle > span {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
}

span.spanRojo {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="calle">
  <span class="spanRojo"></span>
  <span class="spanNegro"></span>
</div>

<br/><br/>

<span id="noTocado">Tocado: No</span>
<span id="siTocado">Tocado: Sí</span>
```