# ¿Cómo averiguar si el elemento ha salido por completo de otro?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Lo que intento hacer es averiguar cuando un elemento (cuadrado negro) se sale **completamente** (no quede nada del cuadrado negro dentro del azul) del otro elemento (cuadrado azul).

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].addEventListener("mousedown", mover);
   function mover(e){
       elem = e.target;//obtener elemento
      function pocisionar(pageX, pageY){
          elem.style.left = pageX -  elem.offsetHeight/2 + 'px';
          elem.style.top = pageY -  elem.offsetHeight/2 + 'px';
          
      }
      function obtener(event){
           pocisionar(event.pageX, event.pageY);
       }
      elem.addEventListener('mousemove', obtener);
      elem.addEventListener('mouseup', eliminar);
       function eliminar(e){
         elem.removeEventListener('mousemove', obtener);
        }
     }
```

```css
div{
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: aqua;
    }
 p{
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: black;
        position: absolute;
 }
```

```html
<div>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Pensé en resolverlo con `getBoundingClientRect()` pero no se me ocurre como. Además de esta idea, ¿Se les ocurren otra forma de resolverlo?, ¿Algún consejo?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claro, con `getBoundingClientRect()` lo resolverías, con éste método tendrías acceso a las coordenadas de `p` (cuadro negro) y al `div` (cuadro celeste) y luego podrías validar que si la posición de la coordenada de `p` supera a la del `div`, muestre un `span` con dicho texto, en [**ésta respuesta**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/575388/c%C3%B3mo-detectar-que-un-elemento-pas%C3%B3-por-encima-del-otro/575415#575415) explico a más detalle. Tu código sería el siguiente:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].addEventListener("mousedown", mover);

const siSalio = document.getElementById('siSalio'); // obtengo al span => <span id="siSalio">Salió del cuadro celeste</span>
const noSalio = document.getElementById('noSalio'); // obtengo al span => <span id="noSalio">No salió del cuadro celeste</span>

siSalio.style.display = 'none'; // por defecto oculto al span "siSalio".
noSalio.style.display = 'block'; // por defecto muestro al span "noSalio".

function mover(e) {
  elem = e.target; // obtener elemento

  function pocisionar(pageX, pageY) {
    elem.style.left = pageX - elem.offsetHeight / 2 + "px";
    elem.style.top = pageY - elem.offsetHeight / 2 + "px";
  }

  function obtener(event) {
    pocisionar(event.pageX, event.pageY);

    const pCord = document.querySelector("p").getBoundingClientRect(); // obtengo las coordenadas de "p" (cuadro negro)
    const divCord = document.querySelector("div").getBoundingClientRect(); // obtengo las coordenadas de "div" (cuadro celeste)

    // valido las coordenadas de ambos elementos
    if (pCord.right < divCord.left || pCord.left > divCord.right || pCord.top > divCord.bottom || pCord.bottom < divCord.top) {
      siSalio.style.display = 'block';
      noSalio.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      siSalio.style.display = 'none';
      noSalio.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }

  elem.addEventListener("mousemove", obtener);
  elem.addEventListener("mouseup", eliminar);

  function eliminar(e) {
    elem.removeEventListener("mousemove", obtener);
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

p {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p></p>
</div>
<br>
<span id="siSalio">Salió del cuadro celeste</span>
<span id="noSalio">No salió del cuadro celeste</span>
```

Comment: Gracias! Pero no me sirve . Quiero que me diga que el cuadrado negro salió del celeste cuando ya no quede nada del negro dentro.

Comment: @Roberto edité mi respuesta, solo se tuvo que cambiar la validación de las coordenadas, me confirmas.

Comment: Gracias! Ya me funciona! 